# Efficiently merge two lists

Tags: list, haskell, merge, compiler-errors

I'm currently learning Haskell, and working with `List`.

According to the [HaskellWiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/How_to_work_on_lists), if I wanted to merge two lists together, I would write:

```
list1 ++ list2
```

However, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53123141/10641593) answer, using ++ on a large list would be inefficient.

From researching, I came across [this SO page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938438/merging-two-lists-in-haskell), but that question requires a specific requirement for the output of the `List`.

**What I tried**:

Suppose if I had two lists of  numbers (for this example, assume that both lists are large enough that using `++` would be inefficient as described in the SO answer):

```
 oldNumbers = [1,5,14,22,37]
 newNumbers = [3,10,17,27,34,69]
 allNumbers = oldNumbers:newNumbers
```

As you can see I attempted to add `oldNumbers` to the head of `newNumbers` with the intention of reversing it afterward (disregard that `allNumbers` would be unorder for now, that's an exercise for another day).

As you probably guessed, it produced an error

```
error:
    * Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num [a]
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    * When checking the inferred type
        allNumbers :: forall a. (Num a, Num [a]) => [[a]]
```

So, as stated in the title, how would I efficiently merge two lists?

Comment: `(++)` is not inefficient in the sense that it works in linear time. The idea is that `(++)` however is sometimes "misused" to append a single element to a list turning the algorithm in *O(n^2)* instead of *O(n)*.

Comment: correctness first, efficiency later. really. -- so are you merging two sorted lists, and the merged list must be sorted as well? if not, there's absolutely nothing wrong with one-time `++`. the answer you cite talks about *repeated* appending of *one-element* lists with `++ [x]` being "bad".

Comment: @WillNess - The merged list doesn't have to be sorted. I'm taking small steps, so for now the mission is to merge the two lists. I'll `sort` them later when I understand `List` in Haskell better.

Comment: then `++` does the job. do you want to re-implement it, as an exercise? is your question about that ,or about the error you got?

Comment: @WillNess - No, not right now. I was just wondering about the answer I cited, it said using `++` was inefficient, so it made me wonder what I sould do instead, the answer also stated to add it to the head of the list and reverse it, which I attempted, but received an error. But as you pointed out, `++` is fine here.

Comment: Hey, that's my answer. I never said `++` was inefficient.

Comment: @melpomene - I probably misinterpreted what you stated. I way I read it was using `++` to merge one and only one element was fine, but when the lists are huge using `++` would be inefficient because of the copying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> According to the [HaskellWiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/How_to_work_on_lists), if I wanted to merge two lists together,
>   I would write:
>
> ```
> list1 ++ list2
> ```
>
> However, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53123008/correct-way-to-add-an-element-to-the-end-of-a-list/53123141#53123141), using `++` on a large list would be
>   inefficient.

I think you need to take the context into account in this answer. If we append two lists `a` and `b` with `(++)` then it appends the two lists in *O(m)* (with *m* the length of the list). So this is, in terms of time complexity efficient. One can not construct such singly linked list more efficient than that.

[@melpomene](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53123141/67579) actually points to a popular mistake people new to Haskell make: they append a *single* element at the end of the list. Again if you only want to append a *single* element to the list, that is not a problem. This is a problem if you want to append *n* elements that way to a list, so if you each time append a single element to the list, and you do that *n* times, then the algorithm will be *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*.

So in short, from a time complexity point of view, `(++)` is not slow when you append two lists together, nor is it slow when you append a singleton list to it. There are however, in terms of asymptotic behavior, usually better ways than repeatedly appending a list with one element to a list, since then the first operand will typically become larger, and each iteration it takes *O(n)* time only to append a single element to a list. Typically one can use recursion on the tail element of a list in that case, or for example build the list in reverse.

`(++)` is thus not "intrinsically" inefficient, by by using it in ways for which it was not design, you can obtain inefficient behavior.

An example where `++` will be quite slow is the following function that performs a "mapping":

```
badmap :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
badmap f = go []
    where go temp [] = temp
          go temp (x:xs) = go (temp ++ [f x]) xs
```

There are two problems here:

1. it is not lazy, it requires to evaluate the entire list before this can emit the first element; and
2. it will run in quadratic time, since for each element in the input list, it will take more and more time to append this element.

A more effective way to implement a map is:

```
goodmap :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
goodmap f = go
    where go (x:xs) = f x : go xs
          go [] = []
```

Comment: where does it say in the Report that lists are "singly linked"? I couldn't find anything like that there. The complexity of `++` seems not to be specified either.

Comment: @WillNess: conceptually it is a sinly linked list, since there is no direct link in the data definition to the "parent". Furthermore that would also be strange, since one can reuse the tail, so there is no "previous". The time complexity follows from the implementation in the Haskell report on the standard prelude:  https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/standard-prelude.html

Comment: conceptually it could just as well be implemented on arrays with O(1) append. the implementation gives value semantics for the types / functions, not operational semantics / performance.

Comment: @WillNess: indeed, and then it is still *O(n)*, *O(n!)*,... Somehow this discussions feels a bit like the one I had with some friends about the first chapter of "*Computational Complexity*": "Why the computational model does not matter".

Comment: I really like this answer, but could you provide example code of *append n elements that way to a list*? It will help understand better of what **not** to do.

Answer (score 4):

There's absolutely nothing wrong with appending two lists with *one-time* `++`, however long they are.

The answer you cite, (rightfully) talks about *repeated* appending of *one-element* lists with `++ [x]` being "bad".

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to efficiently append arbitrary lists, use a different data structure! Data.Seq is optimized for efficient appends, for example.

https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.19/containers-0.5.11.0/Data-Sequence.html#v:-62--60-