# Trying to understand how not to add elements to a list

Tags: list, haskell

As a followup to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53352740/10641593), I'm attempting to understand how **not** to add element**s** to a `list` using `++`.

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53352985/10641593) answer:

> Again if you only want to append a single element to the list, that is
>   not a problem. **This is a problem if you want to append n elements that
>   way to a list, so if you each time append a single element to the
>   list, and you do that n times, then the algorithm will be O(n2)**.

So from my understanding, this means you **shouldn't** do this:

```
let numbers = [1,3,5,10,15]
newNumbers = numbers ++ [27]
listofnumbers = newNumbers ++ [39]
```

Is this what the bold text in the quoted answer telling you not to do? If not, using code, what is the bold text warning you not to do?

Comment: If you are adding multiple items to a list, it is more efficient to append all of the times at once, rather than looping through, adding one at a time.

Comment: You have to find a way to change your appending order from left associative to right associative. In another words you shouldn't do like `((numbers ++ new1) ++ new2) ++ new3)` but `(numbers ++ (new1 ++ (new2 ++ new3)))`. I would also advise you to have a look at [difference lists](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more) towards the end of the chapter.

Comment: check out [this canonical answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13879693/849891) by [Daniel Fischer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1011995/daniel-fischer) (also maybe [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14942678/849891) (disclaimer: it's by me)) which talk about this stuff.

Comment: incidentally that [second question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14938584/haskell-foldl-poor-performance-with) *answers* your question here, with the example code it uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer talks about a bad time complexity when it comes to appending elements to the *end* of the list. When you concat a list `xs` of length *m* and a list `ys` of length *n* together using `(++)` then `xs ++ ys` will have time complexity *O(m)* (under the assumption you evaluate `xs ++ ys` for a number of steps in proportion to *m*).

So if your list `ys` consists of a single element `y` (that is `ys == [y]`) then `[y] ++ xs` will be *O(1)* because you add it to the beginning but `xs ++ [y]` will be *O(m)* because you add it to the end of another list. So when you repeatedly add elements to the end of another list you will end up with *O(m^2)*. So better do it within one go so you will have *O(m)*.

Note that lists in Haskell are actually stacks which could have an infinite number of elements.

Comment: if `xs++ys` is *O(m)* where `m = length xs`, how come `head ([1..]++[0])` doesn't take infinite time?

Comment: @WillNess Because of laziness. The time complexities from my answer where under the assumption you need to do a full evaluation and `xs` is finite.

Comment: perhaps this assumption is important and should be included explicitly then. :)

Comment: @WillNess Well I could do `(xs ++ ys) !! (m - 1)` which would indeed need *m* steps. But it is under the assumption of a full evaluation of the expression of course.

Comment: this is too vague. what if we have `ys = xs++[y]; zs = ys++[z]`. if `ys` is O(m) only after full access, this seems to leave `zs` with only one more step to be done, so *it* would now seem to become O(1) all of a sudden. the precise [canonical answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13879693/849891) already exists BTW. :)

Comment: @WillNess I honestly wonder if it is important, especially because I rarely come across this assumption when reading reflections by other people on time/space complexity of Haskell expressions (apart from papers which I do not read). But let me add it to the answer.

Comment: @WillNess But full access of `zs` is still *O(m)* after all.

Answer (score 0):

Try these two functions with a large list (like [1..10000]) and see if you notice any difference:

```
func1 a [] = a
func1 a (x:rest) = func (a ++ [x]) rest


func2 a b = a ++ b
```